# GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController GoogleMap Search Listing Layout Issue

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm stuck in a situation. I'm using Places Autocomplete (by Google).

**Ref Link: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete#add_a_search_bar_to_the_navigation_bar**

Its implemented properly. But when a user search any address and tilt the device to up or down, the result list change its position and its looks bad.

**Video Reference: https://gofile.io/d/b3Cd1j**

Below is my code where I have setup Places Autocomplete Search Bar:

```
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.country = "US"
    
    resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
    resultsViewController?.autocompleteFilter = filter
    resultsViewController?.delegate = self
    
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
    searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController
    searchController?.delegate = self
    
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        searchController?.automaticallyShowsCancelButton = false
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    
    // Put the search bar in the navigation bar.
    searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController?.searchBar
    
    // When UISearchController presents the results view, present it in
    // this view controller, not one further up the chain.
    definesPresentationContext = true
    
    // Prevent the navigation bar from being hidden when searching.
    searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    
    searchController?.searchBar.isHidden = true
```

Can anyone help me in this ?